# Enabling java security manager limits udp sockets count

Tags: java, sockets, policy, securitymanager

I have the java app with a custom security policy and when I tried to open 100 udp sockets I've got exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: maximum number of DatagramSockets reached
```

Test app:

```
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;   

public class Test {
    static int basePortNum = 40000; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DatagramSocket> socks = new ArrayList<DatagramSocket>();
        try{
            for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
                socks.add(new DatagramSocket(basePortNum+i, Inet4Address.getByName("127.0.0.1")) );
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            for(java.net.DatagramSocket soc: socks){
                soc.close();
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

If I launch it without security manager it creates all 100 sockets:

```
0
1
...
98
99
```

But if I add this line to VM arguments

```
-Djava.security.manager
```

It fails even with default security policy:

```
0
1
...
23
24
java.net.SocketException: maximum number of DatagramSockets reached
    at sun.net.ResourceManager.beforeUdpCreate(ResourceManager.java:53)
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.create(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:74)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.createImpl(DatagramSocket.java:318)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:209)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:262)
    at Test.main(Test.java:16)
```

How can I change socket limit while using security manager?

UPD: it was reproduced on windows 8.1 x64, windows 7 x64 and windows xp sp3 x32, windows 7 x32. On all systems JDK 1.6.45 x32 was used.

UPD2: on windows xp sp3 x32 reproduced with JDK7 too,  but can't reproduce this with JDK 1.6.27.

UPD3: debugging JDK classes found this:

```
// Compiled from ResourceManager.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class sun.net.ResourceManager {

  // Field descriptor #14 I
  private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_SOCKETS = 25;
```

In open JDK implementation the default socket limit is 1024 
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/ResourceManager.java.html

Comment: There is no `sun.net.ResourceManager` in my copy of the JDK 1.6u23 source code.

Comment: Your edit indicates you were using 1.5, not 1.6.

Comment: Just checked rt.jar in JDK1.6.45 and in JDK1.6.27 ResorceManager.class in place.

Comment: That is how eclipse shows, but as I think this classes remains in sun property so there is no sources for them and so they was added to rt.jar as precompilled.

Comment: No. I have the entire JDK source for 1.6u23, not just what's in src.zip. The version shown in your edit is 1.5.

Comment: Yes, that is how eclipse shows, but I have only JDK 1.6.0_45 in the system. Check your rt.jar file there must be class file for ResourceManager. BTW: found the solution, anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: *Of course* there must be a class for `sun.net.ResourceManager,` but not in 1.6 according to the evidence here.

Comment: java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl line 71
protected synchronized void create() throws SocketException {
 fd = new FileDescriptor();
 fd1 = new FileDescriptor();
        ResourceManager.beforeUdpCreate();

Comment: There is usage of ResourceManager in 1.6 sources

Comment: That line of code does not appear in the source code for `java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl` as of JDK 6u23 FCS. Where did you get it?

Comment: If I remember correctly that was from 1.6.45 sources, sorry this is already 1 year old and I've found solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That VM argument helped:

-Dsun.net.maxDatagramSockets=101

Comment: or if you want to do it programmatically: `System.setProperty("sun.net.maxDatagramSockets","101");`

Comment: using `System.setProperty` may or may not work because `ResourceManager` reads this value in its static block (https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/ResourceManager.java). It depends on how early you set it.